# if __name__ == "__main__": and recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion, program-entry-point, python-module, idioms

I had a confusion regarding `if __name__ == "__main__":` in Python and came across the same question on SO: [What does if **name** == "**main**": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/10358768)

Thanks to the most voted, detailed, and helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/10358768) by [Mr Fooz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25050/mr-fooz), my understanding has improved. However, I'm still confused in one of the code blocks in the same answer:

`foo3.py`:

[image]

Note: Instead of the code block, I've put a snapshot because it has line numbers. Through that, I think I can properly explain what my current understanding is and what my confusion is!

From my understanding, upon running `python3 foo3.py`:

1. print `t1` (line 14)
2. print `t2`
3. call `functionA`
4. print `a1`
5. invoke `foo3` as a module (line 6)
6. So, print `t1` again
7. print 'm1` again
8. call `functionA` again
9. print `a1` again
10. invoke `foo3` as a module again
11. ...
12. ...

So, basically, a neverending `t1 ... m1 ... a1 ...`:

```
t1
m1
a1
t1
m1
a1
t1
m1
a1
.
.
.
```

I was expecting such infinite output because there is no `__name__ == "__main__"` check in `foo3.py` and it keeps invoking itself in `functionA`.

However, when I run this code, I get the following finite output:

```
t1
m1
a1
t1
m1
a1
a2
b
a3
m2
t2
a2
b
a3
m2
t2
```

I still don't understand why!? Shouldn't there be an infinite output? Could anyone please explain the program sequence in the above code snippet?

Comment: Importing the same file multiple times doesn't re-run the code.

Answer (score 1):

A module is only *created* once. The second and subsequent imports don't actually do anything: the module was already created and stored in `sys.modules`, and the name `foo3` is just (re)bound to that module.

`import` doesn't "call" the module; it just makes it available in the current scope, creating the module if necessary as a side effect.

---

One subtlety is that there are two distinct modules, both of which are defined by the *file* `foo3.py`. When you run the script, a module named `__main__` is created. The *first* time `from foo3 import functionB` is executed, a new module named `foo3` is created. But the subsequent `import` statements executed by `functionA` will see `foo3` as having been created already.

Comment: But in that case, importing `foo3` for the first time in `foo3.py` itself (i.e. in one of the functions of `foo3.py`) shouldn't even invoke `foo3` at all, right? I'm more of a C++ guy so I'm still kind of confused here! I'm thinking that "`functionA` invoking import of foo3" and later on "`functionA` of that invoked foo3 trying to invoke foo3 again" are two different things/instances.

Comment: There are two *different* modules, both defined using the *file* `foo3.py`. The first, `__main__`, is created when you run `foo.py` as a script. The second, `foo3`, is created when you try to import `foo.py` the first time.

Comment: I see. So, upon running `foo3.py`, `__name__ = __main__` but in all the subsequent imports, `__name__ = foo3` and that's how the modules are being tracked, correct? It's different from calling the same function within that function (i.e. recursion) in which there is no such tracking, isn't it? Please correct me if I'm mistaken. Thank you for your answer, time, and comment!

Comment: Correct; there is no "recursive" import, because the `import` statement doesn't read or execute the contents of `foo3.py` if a module named `foo3` is already found in `sys.modules`.